# What is the use case for gwt's CssResource.Import annotation?

Tags: gwt, cssresource

What is the use case for gwt's CssResource.Import annotation?

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/resources/client/CssResource.Import.html

Answer (score 1):

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CssResource#Imported_scopes ?